# Why am I having an issue with Code Runner compiling C?

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Hi I'm using vscode I've been using it fine for a year or two.
For some reason the last week code runner started acting up it tries to run my C code in git bash terminal and it gives me an error instead of running in PowerShell.
My default terminal profile is powershell.
I can't figure out why code runner opens a git bash terminal to run the code. Any solutions?

Edit:

Sometimes no error message appears but also there is no output and sometimes this error appears : bash: syntax error near unexpected token '{'

Help please